# Find duplicates in array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I'm working on a simple JavaScript web-based game. The goal is to guess a X digit random number. This means the random number can be 4, 5 digits up to whatever you want. You can actually play the game at www.juegodescifralo.com , (it's in Spanish, sorry about that).

The user inputs a number that is stored as an array. The random number is also generated as an array. Individual numbers in both arrays can be repeated.

There are three types of possible "values/numbers": the "good" ones are the numbers you chose that are in the same position as the ones in the random array. So for example:

Random array is: 14**5**7

User input is: 68**5**1

Number 5 is a "good" number, since it's in the same position. Then there are the second type of "values", which are "regular". This means they are inside the random number but not in the same position. In this example, number 1 would be a "regular" value. And the third type is the "bad" ones, which are not even inside the random array.

The function I've developed is as follows:

```
function checkNumbers(randomArray, myArray, good, regular, bad) {
    for (var x = 0; x < randomArray.length; x++) {
        var posRepetido = randomArray.indexOf(myArray[x]); //Is current number inside random array?

        if (posRepetido == -1) { //It's not inside
            console.log("number " + myArray[x] + "is not inside");
            bad++;

        } else { //It's inside

            regular++;

            if (myArray[x] == randomArray[x]) { //If it's the same number...
                console.log("number " + myArray[x] + "is in the correct position");

                good++;
                regular--;
            } else { //If it's not the same number

                if (randomArray[posRepetido] != myArray[posRepetido]) {
                    console.log("number " + myArray[x] + "is inside but not in the same position");

                } else {
                    console.log("number " + myArray[x] + "is not inside");

                }
            }
        }
    }

    var obj = { //Return object for accessing later, to show feedback to the user.
        good: good,
        regular: regular,
        bad: bad
    };

    return obj;
}
```

The code is a bit buggy. When there are duplicates in the random array, and one of them is marked as good, then the other one (even if it exists in user input) will be set as bad, not as regular as it should.

The thing becomes even more complicated since you should be able to play against any amount of digits. So I should be able to guess a 20 digit number without "problems".

You can play by yourself at www.juegodescifralo.com

How can I go about this? Any ideas how can I access array data more easily? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `indexOf` comparisons against `-1` and checks of `myArray[x]`, it would probably be a lot easier to use `includes` and array methods such as `forEach` for better abstraction. All you really need is an `if`, an `else if`, and an `else`. For example:

```js
function checkNumbers(randomArray, userArray, good=0, regular=0, bad=0) {
  userArray.forEach((guess, i) => {
    if (guess === randomArray[i]) good++;
    else if (randomArray.includes(guess)) regular++;
    else bad++;
  });
  return { good, regular, bad };
}



// 4 good
console.log(checkNumbers(
  '1234'.split(''),
  '1234'.split(''),
));
// 4 good, 2 bad
console.log(checkNumbers(
  '1234'.split(''),
  '123456'.split(''),
));
// 4 good, 2 regular
console.log(checkNumbers(
  '1234'.split(''),
  '123412'.split(''),
));
// all regular:
console.log(checkNumbers(
  '123456789123456789'.split(''),
  '912345678912345678'.split(''),
));
```

Comment: This is a really good step forward. However, when comparing to my code, it returns the same in the following example:

Random Array: 81885
User Array: 85111

Returns: 1 good, 4 regular. Even though it really is 1 good 2 regular and 2 bad, since there are two extra ones in the user input. That is really the problem, being able to differentiate between repeated "extra" characters. It's giving me a headache. I didn't know about "forEach" in JavaScript. Thank you! I'll keep researching to see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is easier to loop thru it twice like this

```
function checkNumbers(randomArray, guessArray) {
  var clone = randomArray.slice(0);
  var good = 0;
  var regular = 0;
  var bad  = 0;
  var visited = [];

  guessArray.forEach(function(guess, index) {
    if (guess === clone[index]) { // the guess is in right position
      good++;
      clone[index] = "x"; // strike it out so it cannot be used later
      visited.push(index);
    } else if (clone.indexOf(guess) === -1) {
      bad++;
      visited.push(index);
    }
  });
  guessArray.forEach(function(guess, index) {
    if (!visited.includes(index)) {
      var match = clone.indexOf(guess);
      if (match !== -1) {
        regular++;
        clone[match] = "x"; // strike it out so it cannot be used later
      }
    }
  });

  return {
    good: good,
    bad: bad,
    regular: regular
  }
}
```

first loop is to check the good and bad. and strikeout the value it is good so it cannot be used again.

second loop to check for the regular and strikeout the value it is used so it cannot be used again.

Comment: It's getting a bit hard for me to understand the code... However, when trying the example given to CertainPerformance (random [8, 1, 8, 8, 5] user [8, 5, 1, 1, 1]) the function somehow returns 1 good 1 regular and 0 bad. Also, the striked numbers become the first two of the random arr ([x, x, 8, 8, 5]). Why is this the result? Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry, this is a bug in may code :-( I have updated my answer

Comment: Now, given the example in my first comment (the one with 5 digits), it is returning 1 good, 0 bad, 2 regular. Something similar happens with the examples you gave before: [4, 1, 1, 4] and [1, 4, 1, 1] is returning 1 good, 0 bad, 2 regular as well. I don't really know the cause... Also somehow the bad ones are not being recorded, when they should, because every extra number that is repeated should be a "bad" number. Thank you beforehand!

Comment: sorry maybe I have misunderstood the logic. with [4, 1, 1, 4] and user = [1, 4, 1, 1], we have 1 good user [x,x,1,x] and 2 regular [1, 4, x, x]

Comment: Ok so it seems that I haven't explained myself correctly, or maybe I'm not understanding what you mean haha. Have you tried playing the game? Even though it's in Spanish, maybe you get the idea. www.juegodescifralo.com

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
function guessNumber (numUser, numRandom) {
    if (typeof numUser == 'number') {
        numUser = numUser.toString().split('');
    }
    if (typeof numRandom == 'number') {
        numRandom = numRandom.toString().split('');
    }
 
    if (typeof numRandom != 'object' || typeof numUser != 'object') {
        return false;
    }
 
    if (numRandom == numUser) {
        return true;
    }
 
    var numRegular = {},
        numBuenos = {},
        numMalos = {},
    numRepeat = {};
 
 
    for(var i  = 0; i < numRandom.length; i++) {
      if (!numRepeat[numRandom[i]]) {
        numRepeat[numRandom[i]] = 0;
    }
      numRegular[numRandom[i]] = 0;
      numRepeat[numRandom[i]]++;
  }
 
 
    for (var i  = 0; i < numUser.length; i++) {
        if (numUser[i] == numRandom[i]) {
            numBuenos[numUser[i]] = numUser[i];
        }else if ($.inArray(numUser[i], numRandom)) {
      if (!numRegular[numUser[i]]) {
        numRegular[numUser[i]] = 0;
      }
      if (numRegular[numUser[i]] < numRepeat[numUser[i]]) {
          numRegular[numUser[i]]++;
      } else {
                numMalos[numUser[i]] = numUser[i];
      }
        } else {
            numMalos[numUser[i]] = numUser[i];
        }
    }
 
 
    return {
        regular: Object.values(numRegular).reduce((a, b) => a + b),
        buenos: Object.keys(numBuenos).length,
        malos: Object.keys(numMalos).length
    };
 
}
 
console.log(guessNumber(8365, 8512));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you please add some explanation about what you have changed and what was the problem?